# Array not being filled (JSON object)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to ready a JSON output into an array in iOS. But the array is not being filled at all. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void) retrieveData;

{


    NSString *getDataURL = @"http://localhost:8888/finalproject/ios/getHouseBills.php";

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    houseBillsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    long test = jsonArray.count;


    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
         NSString * hBID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"houseBillID"];
        NSString * hID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"houseID"];
        NSString * hName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * hAmount = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"amount"];
        NSString * hDate = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSString * hAddedBy = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"addedBy"];

        [houseBillsArray addObject:[[House alloc]initWithHouseBillID:hBID andHouseID: hID andName: hName andAmount:  hAmount andDate:  hDate andAddedBy:  hAddedBy]];


    }



    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];



}
```

Here is an example of the JSON input it will be taking:

```
[{"houseBillID":"1","houseID":"20","name":"Loo roll","amount":"32453","date":"eqferf","addedBy":"samstone920@googlemail.com"},{"houseBillID":"2","houseID":"20","name":"toothpaste","amount":"3","date":"wefe","addedBy":"44tq"}]
```

Excuse the fact it is mostly gibberish. But yeah, the array isn't being filled at all. Something tells me its down to character sets, but I'm not sure.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: I tried parsing the JSON raw, and that worked fine.

EDIT: The data is being retrieved fine. Just NSLog'ed the data variable.

Comment: You see that `error:` parameter there?  It's there for a reason -- use it!

Comment: What parameter should it take to activate it?

Comment: An `NSError*`.  `NSError* error; jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization ... error:&error]; if (jsonArray == nil) { NSLog(@"JSON error = %@", error); }`

Comment: this is the error: `JSON error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x10a782460 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}` Having a google now, but if you have any first hand info it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, NSLog the NSData object and dig out your ASCII chart and start decoding.  (I suggest working from the back end.)

Comment: No problem.  It's been pleasant working with someone who actually wants to listen to advice.

Comment: If you want to put an answer, I will gladly mark it.

Comment: Nah, you can put it in an answer and accept it yourself, if you want.